# Calculate $\int_C \frac {x^3dy-y^3dx}{x^{5/3}+y^{5/3}}$ where $C:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ in the first quadrant

Tags: integration, curves

> Calculate $\displaystyle\int_C \frac {x^3dy-y^3dx}{x^{5/3}+y^{5/3}}$ where  $C:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ in the first quadrant.

My attempt:

Parametrization:
$$x(t)=a\cos^3t$$
$$y(t)=a\sin^3t$$

Then the integral becomes $$I=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}2}\frac {\sin^2t\cos^{10}t+\cos^2t\sin^{10}t}{\cos^5t+\sin^5t}dt$$

And I'm stuck here.

Comment: Are you sure that the exponents in the nominator are $3$ and not, say, $2$?

Comment: @user Yes, it is 3